# How can I use pipes to send a flag to a child process?

Tags: c, linux, pipe, fork, posix

I need to make a program that asks for an integer, pipes the input to a child process, squares inside the child, pipes back to the parent, and then asks for another input.

I could do this without the loop, but then I cannot for the life of me figure out the sequence I'd need to call fork() and read().

Here is what I have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void){

    int psocket[2];
    int csocket[2];
    int csig[2];
    int sig = 0;

    pid_t child;

    if(read(csig[0], &sig, sizeof(int)) == -1)
        perror("reading signal");

    if(sig){
        int square;

        if(read(csocket[0], &square, sizeof(int))==-1)
            perror("read to child");

        square = square * square;

        if(write(psocket[1], &square, sizeof(int))==-1)
            perror("write to parent");

        return 0;
    }
    
    while(1){
        int value;
        sig = 1;

        printf(">> ");
        scanf("%d", &value);

        if(value ==0)
            break;

        if(write(csocket[1], &value, sizeof(int))==-1)
            perror("write to child");
        if(write(csig[1], &value, sizeof(int))==-1)
            perror("write to signal");

        child = fork();
        wait(NULL);

        if(read(psocket[0], &value, sizeof(int))==-1)
            perror("read to parent");

        printf("\n>> %d\n", value);
    } 

    return 0;
}
```

But I get an error trying to read/write the csig pipe

```
reading signal: Bad file descriptor
>> 32 //entering a value to test
 write to signal: Bad file descriptor
```

I am completely lost at this point. Is there another way to go about this? Something obvious I am doing wrong?

**EDIT:**

I realized I forgot to make a call to pipe()

I added

```
if ((pipe(psocket) < 0) || (pipe(csocket) < 0) || (pipe(csig) < 0)) {
        perror("opening stream socket pair");
        exit(10);
}
```

after variable initialization and now the program hangs.

Comment: You're using uninitialized variables.

Comment: @shawn fixed, I think.

Comment: You are now (assuming I interpret your edit correctly: it would be convenient if you actually edit the question and add the code) creating a pipe and immediately trying to read from it.  Since there are no writers, the read is going to block forever.

Comment: I have at this point isolated that as an issue, but that leaves me still completely clueless how to accomplish this problem. If I cannot make a call to read a yet-unwritten pipe, how can I let the child process know it's a child? If I call fork before the loop, then how can I recursively call new processes?

Comment: The child will know it's a child based on the return value of `fork()`. You are supposed to only fork once per program, and not once per input.

Answer (score 0):

I realized that I can just recursively call the main() process, problem solved

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int main(void){
    int psocket[2];
    int csocket[2];
    pid_t child;

    if(pipe(psocket) < 0 || pipe(csocket) < 0)
        perror("pipe");

    child = fork();
    if(child < 0)
        perror("fork");

    if(child == 0){
        int value = 0;

        if(read(csocket[0], &value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
            perror("read child");

        value = value * value;

        if(write(psocket[1], &value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
            perror("write parent");
    }
    else if (child){
        int value = 0;

        printf(">> ");
        scanf("%d", &value);


        if(write(csocket[1], &value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
            perror("write child");

        wait(NULL);

        if(read(psocket[0], &value, sizeof(int)) < 0)
            perror("read parent");

        printf("Squared: %d\n", value);

        main();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please be aware that if this is an educational assignment, this solution will likely not give full marks as it does not maintain a persistent dialog with the child process and instead keeps forking new ones while leaking stack and FDs.